# How to open a file and display its contents using php?

Tags: php

I have a problem while trying to open a file and display its contents using php

My file called `hello.txt`

Here is my PHP code

```
<?php 

$filename = 'hello.txt';
$filePath = 'c:\\Users\\bheng\\Desktop\\'.$filename;

if(file_exists($filePath)) {
    echo "File Found.";

    $handle       = fopen($filePath, "rb");
    $fileContents = fread($handle, filesize($filePath));
    fclose($handle);

    if(!empty($fileContents)) {
        echo "<pre>".$fileContents."</pre>";
    }

}
else {
    echo "File Not Found.";
}

?>
```

I got this from 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

I keep getting error:

> fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Try file_get_contents to simplify things

Comment: $filename = 'Hello php.txt'; OR $filename = 'hello.txt'; ???

Comment: @andrew : I'm sorry. It's a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Are you trying to open an empty file?

Comment: Worked fine for me. Make sure the path is correct, the folder and file have proper permissions set.

Comment: I got it now working now. Thanks all for your time.

Comment: I couldn't accept it yet, but I think @Elias Van Ootegem got it !

Comment: @Fred-ii- In the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) of the function, it is said that the function uses cache and that you have to call `clearstatcache()`... Hence my answer.

Comment: @Brewal That makes sense. However, by my own test, it did produce the error when the file was empty, then being OK once I added something in it. Therefore, all of this could have easily been avoided had the OP included content in the file and Google'd the error. A simple browser refresh with content would have made the error disappear ;-)

Comment: *I keep getting error fread(): Length parameter must be greater than 0 Can someone help me please ?* - **Answer:** Your file is empty. That, and/or what I said about the path/permissions.

Comment: @Fred-ii- : You're right about everything ! My stupid mistake that leave the file empty in the first place.

Comment: Lol ! Indeed the test should be `if(file_exists($filePath) && filesize($filePath)) {` ! xD

Comment: @evoque2015 *You're right about everything* - Only when I test code on my side and being able to reproduce the error ;-)

Comment: Have a good day gentlemen, *cheers* - oh and ladies too, should there be any present here.

Comment: Consider accepting @Brewal's answer so we can wrap it all up. It pretty much covers it all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are good answers here about using `file_get_contents()` instead, I'll try to explain wht this is not actually working, and how to make it work without changing the method.

`filesize()` function uses cache. You probably executed this code while still having the file empty.

Use the [`clearstatcache`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.clearstatcache.php) function each time the file change, or before testing its size :

```
clearstatcache();
$fileContents = fread($handle, filesize($filePath));
```

Also obviously make sure that your file is not empty ! Test it :

```
clearstatcache();
if(file_exists($filePath) && filesize($filePath)) {
    // code
}
```

Comment: Another happy ending ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It needn't be that hard, and it certainly doesn't require you to read a file in binary mode:

```
if (file_exists($filePath))//call realpath on $filePath BTW
{
    echo '<pre>', file_get_contents($filePath), '</pre>';
}
```

All in all, you really don't want to be doing this kind of stuff too much, though

Comment: You want to give us all a quick tips on why this kind of stuffs is not good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to read the entire file's content, there is a shortcut function
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php
So you don't need to bother creating a file handler and closing it afterwards.

```
$fileContents = file_get_contents($filePath);
```

Answer (score 1):

using file_get_contents method of php

```
echo file_get_contents("text.txt");
```

Comment: Convert the whole things into one line ! I like that ! :)

Comment: @evoque2015:... put produces errors if the file doesn't exist, hence I included the `file_exists` check in my answer

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem : You're right - about that. I totally forget about that for a second.